# How to get the current subproject when defining the subprojects closure in the root project

Tags: gradle

I have a multi project gradle build where I'm trying to create some default configuration in the `subprojects` closure.  For example if my root project gradle.build might look like this:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'datadensity'

    ext {
        dataDirectory = "${System.getProperty("user.home")}/Document/data"
    }

    datadensity {
        customer = subproject.rootDir.name     // it's here I'd like to find the current subproject that I'm in.
        output = "src/assets"
        src = "${dataDirectory}/${customer}/src"
        separator = ","
    }
}
```

I have any number of subprojects so using the `project(:blah)` notation isn't going to work since I can't hardcode the name of the subproject.  I'm on Gradle 5.6.4.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is the delegate of the closure is pointing to the subproject's Project instance. Sometimes it helps to RTFM.  So my solution was to change to the following:

```
datadensity {
    customer = projectDir.name
    output = "..."
    ...
}
```